# Creating views with SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, view

I'm new at Android developement, but I'm doing a big app to where I work, I'm the only one who knows something about Android. So, the problem is, I want to do things right. In Android I learned to create and use the database by code in Java, in the SQLiteOpenHelper I create the tables. To use query's I use a controller like this:
This is to search if the login and password exist.

```
Cursor cursor = databaseConnector.getDatabase().query( 
            TABLE_USUARIO,
            new String[] { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NOME, COLUMN_USUARIO, COLUMN_SENHA, COLUMN_MATRICULA, COLUMN_TIPO, COLUMN_SERVIDOR_ID, COLUMN_MUNICIPIO_ID, COLUMN_UNIDADEOPERATIVA_ID, COLUMN_REGIONAL_ID },
            COLUMN_USUARIO + "='" + usuarioUpperCase + "' AND " + COLUMN_SENHA + "='" + senhaUpperCase + "'",
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null );
```

Is there any right ways to do that, or we just do this in Java code?
Any indication of books that help, I would appreciate, thanks.

Comment: you can start by using the `selectionArgs` parameter. Prepare your query and replace the arguments by `?`, then give the arguments in the `selectionArgs` parameter.

Comment: yeah ..you can move like this

Comment: go to this for tutorials [http://www.higherpass.com/android/tutorials/accessing-data-with-android-cursors/](http://www.higherpass.com/android/tutorials/accessing-data-with-android-cursors/)

Comment: also used like `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_USUARIO where  COLUMN_USUARIO=? and COLUMN_SENHA=?", new String[] { usuarioUpperCase,senhaUpperCase });`